# Merging 2 queries in Select COUNT(*) per day

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, union

I have 2 Tables logs and tracks each one holds a timestamp but with different name now I try to get all the logs per day for a given shop and on the same time get the number of tracks per day in my tracks table

```
SELECT DATE(clicktime), COUNT(shop)
FROM LOG
WHERE shop = "shop01"
AND (clicktime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
GROUP BY DATE(clicktime);
```

this query gathers all entries in log table per day and the result looks like

```
--------------------------------
ClickTime          |  Clicks
--------------------------------
2014-12-25         |   342    
-------------------------------- 
2014-12-24         |   232
--------------------------------
```

I get the sales per day on my second Table with following

```
SELECT DATE(last_change) as SaleTime, COUNT(shop) as sale
FROM tracks
WHERE shop = "dd01"
AND (last_change > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
AND relevant = 1
GROUP BY DATE(last_change)
```

Outputs

```
--------------------------------
SaleTime           |  sales
--------------------------------
2014-12-25         |   42    
-------------------------------- 
2014-12-24         |   32
--------------------------------
```

And I would like to merge this 2 queries in one to to have an output like

```
-----------------------------------------
Time               |  sales    |  clicks
-----------------------------------------
2014-12-25         |   42      |  342
----------------------------------------- 
2014-12-24         |   32      |  232
-----------------------------------------
```

I was trying using Union as subquery but this one can't work in may case because different table structures

Is there a way to achieve the desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.clicktime, A.shopCnt, B.saleCount
FROM (SELECT DATE(clicktime) clicktime, COUNT(shop) AS shopCnt
        FROM LOG
        WHERE shop = "shop01"
        AND (clicktime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
        GROUP BY DATE(clicktime)
      ) AS A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DATE(last_change) AS SaleTime, COUNT(shop) AS saleCount
                FROM tracks
                WHERE shop = "dd01"
                AND (last_change > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
                AND relevant = 1
                GROUP BY DATE(last_change)
              ) AS B ON A.clicktime = B.SaleTime
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend that you use a `union` all approach rather than an `inner join`.  If you have days without sales or clicks, then a `join` will drop records:

```
SELECT date, SUM(sales) as sales, SUM(clicks) as clicks
FROM ((SELECT DATE(last_change) as date, COUNT(*) as sales, 0 as clicks
       FROM tracks
       WHERE shop = 'dd01' AND (last_change > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND relevant = 1
       GROUP BY DATE(last_change)
      )
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT DATE(clicktime) as date, 0 as sales, COUNT(*) as clicks
       FROM LOG
       WHERE shop = 'shop01' AND (clicktime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
       GROUP BY DATE(clicktime)
      )
     ) d
GROUP BY date;
```